# Equivalent condition to be $\sigma$-additive in finite case

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**My problem:**

It is well know that if $(X, \mathscr{E},\mu)$ is such that $\mu$ is additive and finite and $\mathscr{E}$ is an algebra $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive if and only if for all $Z_n \downarrow Z$ (in $\mathscr{E}$)  we have $\inf \mu(Z_n) \downarrow \mu(Z)$.

But in the proof of the existence of the infinite product of probability spaces in order to prove a map $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive the author proves this implication:

$$\mbox{If }Z_n \downarrow Z \mbox{ and } \inf \mu(Z_n)=\alpha >0 \mbox{ then } \bigcap_{n}Z_n \neq \emptyset$$

But why is this enough to prove that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_n$'s be disjoint and $E =\cup_n E_n$. Let $Z_n=\bigcup\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} E_k$. Then $\mu (E)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \mu (E_k) +\mu (Z_n)$ by finite additivity. Hence it is enough to show that $\mu(Z_n) \to 0$. Note that $(Z_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of sets so $\mu (E_n)$ is decreasing. If $\lim \mu (Z_n)\equiv \inf_n \mu (Z_n) >0$ then $\cap_n Z_n$ is nonempty. If $x$ is a point this set then $x$ belongs to $E_k$ for infinitely many values of $k$. But $E_k$'s are disjoint so we have arrived at a contradiction.